# addclass to element on different url

Tags: jquery, url, addclass

Trying to find a simple script to add a class to an element on another page.

I want to click on .this-tab and add a .selected class to the corresponding tab on another page. If I click on .that-tab I want to add .selected to its corresponding tab on another page.

Do I need to use a cookie?

Comment: if want to pass data to other page use cookies or pass via GET request

Comment: Is the other page you are referring to an Iframe?

Comment: k.. it is possible. u can paste that code here...

Comment: Giving a unique name to each window will allow you to make that communication directly with JS.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the code you are already using? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just use hashchanged event to achieve what you want, for example: first tab has href="linktopage#select_first_tab", at that page analyse hash trace and select appropriate tab.